# How would one create a UI such as this for an application?

Tags: vb.net, user-interface

Anyone know how I would go about implementing a UI that's very customized, something like this? (Programming in VB.net right now if it matters).

Have yet to deviate from the standard windows form look but I've got a project which I would like to visually style out how I want.
Thanks in advance :)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use WPF.

You can style that however you like.

You will probably be able to find some UI components from companies like Telerik and Infragistics.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a free solution for WinForms check out [Krypton Toolkit](http://www.componentfactory.com/).

It has some nice custom themes..

Answer (score 0):

With a few custom graphics and controls you should be able to reproduce that with VB.Net, although it's been a while so I can't be more specific.